# Convert uploaded pdf file to jpg in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, imagemagick-convert

I am currently beginning to learn CodeIgniter. There is this site that I've been working on.

In this site, users can upload PDF files but they are only allowed to view their uploaded files in JPG format. The question is, how can I convert the PDF file into JPG on the time of upload and store JPG format instead of PDF.

here is the code of my **CONTROLLER**

```
public function upload()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
       {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $data['permission'] = $session_data['permission'];

            if($data['permission']=='Super Admin' || $data['permission']=='Admin'){
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
            }

       }
       else
       {
         redirect('login', 'refresh');
       }
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $first = $session_data['firstname'];
        $last = $session_data['lastname'];
        $dept = $session_data['department'];
        $uploader = $first." ".$last;
        $name = $upload_data['file_name'];
        $path = $upload_data['file_path'];

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_uploaded
                (`uploaded_id`, `name`, `path`,`department`,`uploader`)
                VALUES ('','".$name."',
                '". $path."','".$dept."','".$uploader."')");

        redirect('csfi','refresh');
    }
}
```

I've already read about **Imagick** but I don't know how to use it in CodeIgniter. Can you give me some tutorials and examples or a much easier way to convert PDF to JPG in CodeIgniter?

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Try this link https://forum.codeigniter.com/printthread.php?tid=610

Comment: @msvairam Thank you for your help. But unfortunately, I am using Codeigniter and not the native PHP, is it possible to use ImageMagick in CI?

Comment: Codeigniter is only a php framework. You still have the entire php functionality available to you if it is supported by your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$config                   = array();
$config['allowed_types']  = 'pdf';
$config['overwrite']      = TRUE;
$config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Image manipulation library
$this->load->library('image_lib');

foreach ($notes['name'] as $key => $note) 
{
    $_FILES['notes']['name']      = $notes['name'][$key];
    $_FILES['notes']['type']      = $notes['type'][$key];
    $_FILES['notes']['tmp_name']  = $notes['tmp_name'][$key];
    $_FILES['notes']['error']     = $notes['error'][$key];
    $_FILES['notes']['size']      = $notes['size'][$key];

    $extension                    = pathinfo($_FILES['notes']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $unique_no                    = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $filename[$key]               = $unique_no.'.'.$extension; // with ex
    $filename2[$key]              = $unique_no; // without ex

    $target_path                  = "notes_files/";

    if (!is_dir($target_path))
    {
        mkdir('./'.$target_path, 0777, true);
    }

    $config['file_name']          = $filename[$key];
    $config['upload_path']        = './'.$target_path;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (! $this->upload->do_upload('notes')) 
    {
        return array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    // converting pdf to images with imagick
    $im             = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(160,220);

    $ig = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        try {
            $im->readimage($config['upload_path'].$config['file_name']."[$ig]");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $ig = -1;
        }

        if($ig === -1) break;

        $im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
        $im->setImageAlphaChannel(imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
        $im->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
        $im->setImageFormat('jpg'); 

        $image_name     = $filename2[$key]."_$ig".'.jpg';
        $imageprops     = $im->getImageGeometry();

        $im->writeImage($config['upload_path'] .$image_name); 
        $im->clear(); 
        $im->destroy();

        // change file permission for file manipulation
        chmod($config['upload_path'].$image_name, 0777); // CHMOD file

        // add watermark to image
        $img_manip              = array();
        $img_manip              = array(
            'image_library'     => 'gd2', 
            'wm_type'           => 'overlay',
            'wm_overlay_path'   => FCPATH . '/uploads/institutes/'.$institute_logo, // path to watermark image
            'wm_x_transp'       => '10',
            'wm_y_transp'       => '10',
            'wm_opacity'        => '10',
            'wm_vrt_alignment'  => 'middle',
            'wm_hor_alignment'  => 'center',
            'source_image'      => $config['upload_path'].$image_name
        );

        $this->image_lib->initialize($img_manip);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();

        ImageJPEG(ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($config['upload_path'].$image_name)), $config['upload_path'].$image_name, );

        $ig++;
    }

    // unlink the original pdf file
    chmod($config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'], 0777); // CHMOD file
    unlink($config['upload_path'].$config['file_name']);    // remove file
}
// echo '<p>Success</p>';exit;
die(json_encode(array(
    'data' => 'Success',
    'status' => 'success'
)));
```

> Try this, you can upload and convert multiple files using this.